# Pandas: Apply different filter to dataframe based on the year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I would like to apply different filters to my dataframe if the year is above or below a range. Here is the dataframe

```
dataset=pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5], 
                      'Avail' : [2017,2017,2017,2018,2018,2018,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2018,2018], 
                      'Change' : [0,0,2018,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2018,0,0],
                      'Pref' : [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
                      'Status': ['null', 'null','Q','null','null','null','Q','null','null','null','null','null','Q','null','null']
                      },columns=['ID', 'Avail', 'Change', 'Pref', 'Status'])
```

Here is the code I have written which generates an error:

```
def yearfilt(x):
    if x.loc[:, ['Avail', 'Change']].values.max(axis=1) < 2018:
        if pd.isnull(x.Status):
            x.drop_duplicates(subset=['STU_ID','Status' ], keep='last')
        else:
            x=x.drop(x[pd.isnull(x.Status)].index)
    else:
        if pd.isnull(x.ASSESSMENT_OUTCOME_CD):
            x.drop_duplicates(subset=['STU_ID','Status' ], keep='first')
        else:
         x=x.drop(x[pd.isnull(x.Status)].index)

df=dataset.groupby(['ID']).apply(yearfilt).sort_values(["ID"]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The error is

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

What I would like to perform is:

```
If the max (Avail, Change) < 2018 then
Case 1: the same status --> drop duplicates and keep the last
Case 2: different status --> drop null-value statuses

else (in other words max (Avail, Change) = 2018)
Case 1: the same status --> drop duplicates and keep the first
Case 2: different status --> drop null-value statuses
```

The output should look like:

```
ID  Year  Change  Pref  Status
1   2017   2018    3      Q
2   2018   0       1     null
3   2017   0       1      Q
4   2017   0       3     null
5   2017   2018    1      Q
```

Basically, from each ID I would like to keep only one. 
thank you

Comment: please write  line in which it is giving you trouble ?

Comment: The last line of the code: df=dataset.groupby(['ID']).apply(yearfilt).sort_values(["ID"]).reset_index(drop=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ValueError` you see occurs because you are trying to check `if(some_series)`. I am not sure which line gives the error you've indicated, but it looks like any of your if statements could cause this issue.

For example, the first if statement compares a series of values to a single value. The result is a series of boolean values, not a single True/False which an if statement can make sense of. The same may occur with `pd.isnull`.

You should check which of your commands gives an array result and think about how that fits with the logic of your code.

Here's a possible solution, if I'm understanding your problem correctly:

```
def yearfilt(group):
    # Apply .max() twice to get a single value across the group.
    # Otherwise the results is a Series, and using if will result in a ValueError.
    if group[['Avail', 'Change']].max().max() < 2018:
        # Returns true if there is a unique status value.
        if group['Status'].unique().shape[0] == 1:
            # Return last row as a dataframe.
            return group.iloc[-1:]
        else:
            # Return ALL rows with status not null (may be more than 1?).
            return group[group['Status'] != 'null']
    else:
        if group['Status'].unique().shape[0] == 1:
            # Return first row as a dataframe.
            return group.iloc[:1]
        else:
            return group[group['Status'] != 'null']

dataset.groupby('ID').apply(yearfilt).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Couple of things to remember:

- Each argument passed to the function you use in `groupby().apply` is passed a subset of the whole dataframe. You need to **return** new objects, not modify the groups which your function receives.
- If you are using `isnull`, the values you are trying to filter must be `None`, not the strings `'null'`, `'None'`, `'nan'`, etc. See [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) on missing values.
- You cannot use an `if` statement on a `Series`, only a single value.

Comment: Thank you. But do you have any suggestion to apply a filter based on year, such as the one explained in Case 1,2 above? I am really stuck in this bit

Comment: Have edited the post with a possible solution. Hope it helps!

Comment: This is gold, thank you. It works well on the data sample that I have provided. However, it seems like something is off when I apply that to my extended dataframe that has around 30 columns. I am just trying to figure out why the filter does not give consistent answers. Although my actual dataset has more columns, I only use the columns that I provided in the sample in my post to apply the filter. It is strange!

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the use of `.iloc` to return the first and last indices. `groupby` might not give you a consistent ordering of the subset dataframes, so you may need to use `idxmax`/`idxmin` to get the first/last rows that you want according to some ordering. Also check the behaviour of `group[group['Status'] != 'null']`, because it may return multiple rows.

Comment: you are exactly right about 'null' value. In my actual dataset I have  blanks instead of 'null' values and that is the source of problem. I changed them all to 'Nan' but it seems like that is not taken as unique in python. I also used 'None' to replace white space. That works for all of them except ID 1.

Comment: You need to use `None` (the python constant, **not the string**) for pandas to recognise it with `isnull`. The string `'Nan'` will also not be considered a null value (when you see `nan` in a dataframe representation it is not a string, it is a pandas object representing an empty element). Compare the output of `pd.Series([1, 2, None]).dropna()` with `pd.Series([1, 2, 'None']).dropna()`, and have a read of [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) on missing values.